# Can you compile a file without writing to disk?

Tags: process, pipe, c

I'd like to compile some code from within a C/C++ program. Here's how it would work. I would have a buffer in memory (dynamically allocated) that contains ASCII text that constitutes C code. From my C/C++ I would `fork()` and `exec()` to call the C compiler on the system to compile the code I have in memory.

So I want to know, is there a way I can directly get, let's say, `gcc` to access my code (like with pipes or something?) or do I have to write it to the disk, and read the object code it produces from the disk?

Comment: You would use the library version of your compiler to compile the code. That is rather well documented for all major compilers.

Comment: Does using a memory-mounted filsystem such as `tmpfs` count?

Comment: @Kusalananda I thought of that. But I can't count on /dev/shm always existing, and I thought mounting stuff in C++ might be complicated and fraught with permissions issues. Basically, I want the user to be able to run this program without knowing much intricate details, and for the program to communicate with the compiler (both ways) without using the disk.

Comment: gcc does use temporary files (by default to /tmp). How do you account for this?

Comment: @A.B I think the -pipe flag makes it not use those. Am I wrong?

Comment: The -pipe option is about handling input. Input and temporary files are two different things: /tmp still gets used. In your question you don't explain why you need this. This could help if you explained why, not just how. The easiest way to have all in RAM is to compile using a filesystem in RAM: on Linux tmpfs (when not using swap) or ramfs with more care.

Comment: @A.B Ah, I see. I'm trying to do a sort of genetic programming, where I would keep mutating a program and checking to see whether the mutations are good. To see this, I need to constantly use the compiler and check the object code. But I don't want to keep writing to disk

Answer (score 2):

This could easily have been tested yourself.

```
echo -e '#include <stdio.h>\nmain() {\nputs("hello, world");\n}' |
    gcc -x c -pipe -

./a.out
```

Comment: How would I do this from within C/C++, assuming my program wasn't run with a redirection to gcc?

Comment: `popen(3)` to the compiler. Write the code to it. Remember `pclose(3)` at the end

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way I could also get the output of gcc (the object code it produces) in memory through a pipe?

Answer (score 1):

You would use the library version of your compiler to compile the code. That is rather well documented for all major compilers.

- GCC: [`libgccjit`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/)
- clang: libclang / directly living against llvm / clangDriver
- TCC (C only): [`libtcc`](https://bellard.org/tcc/tcc-doc.html#Libtcc) (because *of course* Fabrice Bellard has written one of the most space-efficient C compilers in existence.)